# Python mod json + urllib2

Tags: python

This is code in python, doesn't work and unknown motive.

```
import json, urllib2
url = 'http://twitter.com/#!/search/PAROusuariosSUBTE'
server = urllib2.urlopen(url)
js = json.load(server)
res = js['results']
for espDeRes in res:
        espDeRes['from_user']
        espDeRes['text']
```

This is error in console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pro.py", line 4, in <module>
    js = json.load(server) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 267, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 338, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any idea?

thanks.

Comment: Who said that 'http://twitter.com/#!/search/PAROusuariosSUBTE' would return JSON? Are you guessing URLs? Think about what you are doing.

Comment: I just love the opening line in this question.

Comment: in this line, doesn't work code 'js = json.load(server)' , because? and think about what your are doing? whats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, your url should be `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=PAROusuariosSUBTE` and it should all work?